# An inequality for a quotient of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove the following to be true for $n > 1$:

$$\frac{n^4}{n^3 + 1} \le Cn$$

It seems like there is some basic rule where you multiply the 1 in the denominator by a value which makes the denominator larger and allows you to combine the denominator into a single term.  But I am struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, note that $n^{4} < n^{4} + n = n (n^{3} + 1)$ for $n > 0$, and divide both sides by $n^{3} + 1 > 0$ to obtain what you want with $C = 1$.